# Polyphony with Pygame channels

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I am trying to trigger audio samples in Python on a Raspberry Pi 3, with physical buttons. The idea is that when I press a button a sound plays. I have been using the Pygame library's channels to achieve (*or at least mimic*) polyphony.

The code that I have been trying to implement is as follows: ([source](https://stenobot.wordpress.com/2017/03/11/building-a-raspberry-pi-sound-grid/))

```
def PlaySound(sound):
nextAvailableChannel = mixer.find_channel(True)
if nextAvailableChannel != None and nextAvailableChannel.get_busy() == False:
    nextAvailableChannel.play(sound)
```

My full script reads:

```
#Import functions
import pygame.mixer as mixer
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

#Initialize mixer
mixer.init(48000, -16, 16, 1024)

#Pin setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

#Create sound objects
bass = mixer.Sound('/home/pi/Desktop/Sounds/bass.wav')
snare = mixer.Sound('/home/pi/Desktop/Sounds/snare.wav')
hat = mixer.Sound('/home/pi/Desktop/Sounds/hihat.wav')

#Defining the channel-picking function
def PlaySound(sound):
    nextAvailableChannel = mixer.find_channel(True)
    if nextAvailableChannel != None and nextAvailableChannel.get_busy() == False:
        nextAvailableChannel.play(sound)
        print(sound, "button pressed")
        sleep(sound / 10)

#Sounds are GO!
while True:
    if GPIO.input(12) == False:
        PlaySound(snare)
    if GPIO.input(16) == False:
        PlaySound(bass)
    if GPIO.input(1) == False:
        PlaySound(hat)
```

Strangely, without `print(sound, "button pressed")` the sounds don't play over each other; the sounds will only play one at a time. (*Bonus question: why is this the case?*)

**Long story short: does anyone know of a better way to achieve polyphony?**

Answer (score 0):

When I try your function, I encounter an Exception in your sleep statement:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Sound' and 'int'
```

What are you trying to accomplish with `sleep(sound / 10)`?. If you remove that, your function should work. Perhaps you meant to sleep for a tenth of the length of the sound, which would be:

```
sleep(sound.get_length() / 10)
```

If you're trying to implement some sort of debounce, then see [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=137484) for a software example, or [here](https://raspberrypihobbyist.blogspot.com.au/2014/11/debouncing-gpio-input.html) for a hardware example.

Okay, looking at the github project linked above, they use `sleep(.3)` as a simple debounce, so that should be sufficient for your purposes.

Also your print statement doesn't really show anything interesting:

```
<Sound object at 0x00515BC0> button pressed
```

The `mixer.Sound` object doesn't retain any information about its construction, printing the length could be useful for your debugging.

Comment: Ah that `sleep(sound / 10)` is a typo or copying error, my actual script reads `sleep(sound.get_length / 10)`, thanks very much for your answer. I will likely implement most/all of your suggestions, I will report back with code revisions